# Executing Scipy Tensor Product

Tags: python, python-2.x, sympy

Can anyone advise on how to use the *SymPy* [TensorProduct](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/quantum/tensorproduct.html) function without having to explicitly indicate the full sequence of objects to take the product of. Below (for the simple case N=3) you can see one of my attempts. But the tensor products are still not coinciding, hence I am still having to write out the full sequence to get the correct answer.

```
import scipy
from numpy import*
import math
from sympy import I, Matrix, symbols
from sympy.physics.quantum import TensorProduct

N = 3

x = array([1/(math.sqrt(2)),1/(math.sqrt(2))])

V =[]
for i in range(1,N+1):
    V.append(x)

V = array(V)

TP1 = TensorProduct(V[0],V[1],V[2])
TP2 = TensorProduct(V[:])

print TP1
print TP2
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Code not working as intended is [not ready for review on CodeReview@SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). That said, try printing  `V`.

Comment: @greybeard The code runs as is above and it prints $V$. The problem is that is does not give the correct tensor product unless I explicitly write out each element of the sequence.

Comment: @JohnDoe try `TP2 = TensorProduct(*V)`; let me know if that works or if I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: @alexyorke That seems to works thanks! I'm not familiar with the '*v' syntax, I'm relatively new to Python. Where can I read up on this?

Comment: @JohnDoe Here is an article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620025/pass-array-as-argument-in-python . I will post my comment as the answer which you can accept to let others know how you solved the problem

Comment: @greybeard It *does* work as intended, it's asking for a specific maintenance optimization. However, this is not the code as OP wrote it. It's an example. Which means this is a specific problem with MCVE, Stack Overflow territory. VTC as example code, will flag for migration.

Comment: I see your point: emphasise it *in the question*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a list of array arguments as individual parameters to a Python function, use the `*` operator:

```
TP1 = TensorProduct(*V)
```

This is equivalent to `TensorProduct(V[0], V[1], V[2],...,V[n])`